# Ending contract without a termination clause

Tags: contract-law, netherlands

We as an association have a contract with two other associations. One of these associations has told us they would like to end the contract.

This contract has no clauses regarding its termination​. As such, we think we should all come to a mutual agreement on how to end the contract. The other association argues that they can just void the contract right now.

Who of us has got it right? Or are we both wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all parties (including the one who wants to end the agreement) signed an addendum terminating that person's participation, that would cover it. There isn't enough information to speak to whether or not they could *just void the contract right now.*

Comment: Based on what information can we determine if they could or not? (Also, thanks for the answer!)

Comment: @SZenC Sorry, are you asking about whether or not they could end the relationship unilaterally?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the unclarity

Comment: Changing a contract is usually a new contract and requires all the normal components of a contract including consideration. Better to use a deed.